# Euclidean geometry and the Euclidean group

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, lie-groups

At Wikipedia's [Erlangen program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program#Abstract_returns_from_the_Erlangen_program) I read that "quite often, it appears there are two or more distinct geometries with isomorphic automorphism groups". Some examples are given.

> But what are examples of geometries nevertheless *being*
>   uniquely defined (up to isomorphism) 
>   by the isomorphism class of their
>   automorphism group?
>
> Are there examples of non-Euclidean
>   geometries with an automorphism group
>   isomorphic to the Euclidean group?

Comment: What is your definition of a **geometry**?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a Lie group $G$ that acts on spaces $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that the point stabilizers $G_p$ act faithfully on $T_pX_i$ for $p \in X_i$, and you want any two such actions to always be conjugate.  Since $G$ always acts on itself, this means it can't have any proper closed subgroups, so it has to be $S^1$, so I think the answer to your question is *no*.

Comment: @Pete: Sorry, I just quoted from the Wikipedia article, but I assume, it's about "spaces" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28mathematics%29)).